# Regex lookahead with multiple negative conditions

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am performing a regex on a HTML string to fetch URL's. I want to fetch all href's and src's that are not javascript. From another SO post I have the following pattern:

```
/(href|src)?\="http:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/(?:(?!\.js).)*"/
```

Which fetches me results like:

```
src="http://www.mydomain.com/path/to/resource/image.gif" alt="" border="0"
```

This is good because it is missing the `.js` results. It's bad because it's fetching additional tags in the element. I tried the following amendment to stop at the first `"`:

```
/(href|src)?\="http:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/(?:(?!\.js).)[^"]*"/
```

It works in that it returns href="$url", but it returns results ending in `.js`. Is there a way to combine a negative lookahead that says:

- Match string until it comes across another `"` - i.e. `[^"]*`; **and**
- Do not match string if it ends in `.js"`

Thanks in advance for any help/tips/pointers.

Comment: What flavour of regex - are lookbehinds available? i.e. `[^"]*(?<!\.js)(?=")` will do what I think you're asking, (but wont work with JavaScript regex, since that doesn't support lookbehind).

Comment: @PeterBoughton PCRE (PHP's `preg_match_all()`). The lookarounds were working as intended, just not as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a "?" to the "*" before the last quote. This will make the "*" non-greedy, ie: it will stop matching at the first quote, not the last

```
/(href|src)?\="http:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/(?:(?!\.js).)*?"/
```

Comment: +1 was about to post this same answer. I would do a `(?:href|src)?` if he is trying to extract URLs.

Comment: There is a typo at `(["http`. Replacing it with just `"http` makes the regex work perfectly. Can this be edited so I can accept it as the answer for future users?

Answer (score 2):

Here's something a bit different. I used Debuggex with this expression:

```
(?:src|href)=(?&.quotStr)(?<!\.js")
```

which compiled it to this one:

```
$regex = '/(?:src|href)=(?:"((?:\\\\.|[^"\\\\]){0,})")(?<!\\.js")/';
```

[Live Demo](http://www.debuggex.com/r/s4GwAFrRrr7YoVsY)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that resource, not seen it before!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to reject `.js` at the end of the string, you can use the following for the last part of the string match:

```
"(?![^"]*\.js").*?"
```

per this [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/WLoH7pLamO)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18838123/1163653 for a better solution.

Fixed it:

```
/(href|src)?\="http:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/(?:(?!\.js"|").)*"/
```

Note that the lookahead is checking for any string (after the domain) that doesn't contain `.js` **or** `"`, both of which would cause it to be invalid. It allows hrefs ending in `.css` through as they only fail when they reach the first `"`, which is the behaviour needed.

Comment: This will also reject anything with a `.js` in the middle of the string as well. Is that what you want?